# Updating uniform buffer objects costs performance?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I replaced the uniforms like mvp matrix in shader with UBO to avoid huge volume of glUniform...() calls. But in order to update the UBO in each frame, I have to call glBufferData() which also costs performance. Now I'm a bit confused of whether to get back to use the uniforms or to use uniform blocks in the shader.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

specifying a bunch of `glUniform` calls will be usually slower than a single call to `glBufferData`, except in the case when you only modify only a few uniform values each frame.

You should thus decide which strategy to adopt based on that. A couple notes:

- Remember that `glBufferData` may not be the best way to update a buffer, because it requires the driver to copy the data from the pointer you provide before returning from the call. I would try using `glMapBufferRange` and write directly the changes into it. Remember that in order to avoid synchronization you need to tell the driver you are not going to read from the pointer it gives to you and that you'll be writing the whole range mapped using the flags `GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT` and `GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_RANGE_BIT`
- Performance of opengl calls is implementation dependent: even if the driver is authorized to perform some optimization such as allocating a new buffer instead of waiting for the old one to be available since you didn't request to be able to use the old content in the mapped range, it could be synchronizing nevertheless, so the only reliable answer you can get is to try both on target hardware and do benchmarks.

Comment: Update: on drivers that support `ARB_buffer_storage`, which is core in OpenGL 4.4, the buffer can be permanently mapped and used at the same time by the video card and the cpu.
This means that there is no more need to copy the data you computed into the mapped buffer, you can directly use the buffer for your CPU computation and then just tell the gpu to render it. The downside is that you need to handle synchronization yourself to avoid artifacts

Comment: if `ARB_buffer_storage` is not available can I just keep getting a buffer pointer to my shared data using `GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT` every frame without much overhead? (I don't need to READ on the CPU side, just WRITE). Ideally a persistent buffer pointer would be great, but I'm using OpenGL ES 3.0 and I'm not sure extension availability is guaranteed on all implementations.

Comment: @Pixel you can avoid a lot of the overhead with `GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT`, but then you have to rewrite the whole buffer each frame. If you can afford to target OpenGL ES 3.1 I suggest you take a look at indirect rendering, which is the new way to do things fast.